# How to run shell command in unrooted device

Tags: android, shell, android-ndk, screenshot

```
$adb push ./asl-native /data/local/asl-native
$adb shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/asl-native
```

above two lines can be executed in unrooted android device using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command in program.

Is there any way to run the below command in unrooted device.
(Note:This command will run correctly in rooted device)

```
$adb shell "/data/local/asl-native /data/local/asl-native.log" &
```

if it is possible using jni or ndk,please explain the steps.

Reference: From ASL(Android Screenshot Library)

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:(`01234ABC` is your device)

```
1)    adb -s 01234ABC shell

2)    shell@android:/ $ run-as com.nitesh.tiwari
```

Hope this could help :)

Comment: Thanks for you reply,second line i cant able to understand,what is this shell@android and where to run this.In program or ??

Comment: @DineshRaj After you hit the first cmd.You will get into shell of your devices.It is jst a path of your shell nothing else

Comment: please tell the exact command to run $adb shell "/data/local/asl-native /data/local/asl-native.log" & . we want to run this using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command or ??